# Strange Picard iteration

Tags: pde, nonlinear-equations, diffusion

I am interested in solving the equation
$$
\begin{aligned} \nabla \cdot\left(\nabla \phi-\frac{\nabla \phi}{|\nabla \phi|}\right) &=0 & & \text { in } \Omega \\ \phi &=0 & & \text { on } \Gamma\left(\phi^{0}\right) \text { and } \\ \nabla \phi \cdot \hat{n} &=\operatorname{sign}\left(\phi^{0}\right) & & \text { on } \partial \Omega 
\end{aligned}
$$
from the paper [A high-order elliptic PDE based level set reinitialisation method using a discontinuous Galerkin discretisation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999118307915). They apply a Picard iteration method (Section 2.2) like
$$
\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi^{m}=\nabla \cdot \frac{\nabla \phi^{m-1}}{\left|\nabla \phi^{m-1}\right|} \quad in~ \Omega
$$
where they solve for $\phi^m$ with $\phi^{m-1}$ from the previous iteration. However, the Picard iteration that I am used to seeing would have been something like
$$
\nabla \cdot\left( \nabla \phi^{m} - \frac{\nabla \phi^{m}}{\left|\nabla \phi^{m-1}\right|}\right)=0\quad in~ \Omega
$$
where one simply assigns the nonlinear terms with values from the previous iterations. This approach does not work however, whereas the one they describe does. I am wondering why. It might have to with the fact that the diffusion term at the current iteration
$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{\left|\nabla \phi^{m-1}\right|}\right)
$$
is zero for $\left|\nabla \phi^{m-1}\right|=1$? And that might require the different strategy they employ? If so, does anybody know of a theory that back that approach?

Comment: As you point out, the linear PDE that you want to solve is degenerate, while theirs is just the Laplace equation. There is some theory for degenerate elliptic PDE based on weighted Sobolev spaces but (personally) I find it pretty hard to understand and I'm not sure how it translates to some more effective numerical method. Equation 13 in that paper I think is really the key and I suspect their might be an even better approach than Picard by using, say, semi-smooth Newton.

Comment: The quantity $\nabla \phi / |\nabla \phi|$ is the level set normal I would suspect your "usual" Picard iteration is not used for this reason.